# Broken dependencies after upgrading from Visual Studio 2017 15.4.5 to 15.5

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that contains:

1. Asp.Net Core 1.1 Project targeting the Full Framework 4.61
2. Several Class Library Projects targeting Full Framework 4.61

This solution compiled without errors in Visual Studio 15.4.5.

I upgraded Visual Studio to version 15.5 and now all my dependencies are broken, see screenshot.

[image]

Interestingly, it turns out that the solution will in compile 15.5 even though it's showing all those warning icons on the dependencies. See below:

[image]

So that's got me really scratching my head. The solution compiles, but Visual Studio is showing all those warning icons on the dependencies. Why? It seems like the dependencies are't broken if the solution compiles. But the warning icons must mean something. Hmmm

Any idea why this happened and what I can do to make all the warning icons disappear from the Web Project's dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Visual Studio 2017 V15.5 doesn't like right parentheses in a project name for some reason, at least not in an Asp.Net Core project.  To figure this out I started by using VS to create a new default Asp.Net Core Project and the dependencies all looked fine.

Then I edited the name of the project in VS to start with 1)  (something I typically do so that the web project will be listed first).  And all the dependencies showed the warning sign.

[image]

The solution still compiles but the warning signs on dependencies remain.  Even closing and reopening the solution dosen't fix it.  Then I changed the name of the name of the project back to not have the ")" char in it and the warning signs on dependencies remain but if I close the solution and reopen it then they dependencies look good again.  Sometimes I found that I needed to close the solution and reopen it to get the fix to show but sometimes it would show right away when I removed the ")" char.  Not sure why the inconsistency.

[image]